# need to create a C# Regex similar to this perl expression

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it is possible to build equivalent C# regular expression for finding this pattern in a filename.  For example, this is the expr in perl `/^filer_(\d{10}).txt(.gz)?$/i`  Could we find or extract the `\d{10}` part so I can use it in processing?

Comment: What is the concrete problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

To create a `Regex` object that will ignore character casing and match your filter try the following:

```
Regex fileFilter = new Regex(@"^filter_(\d{10})\.txt(\.gz)?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase),
```

To perform the match:

```
Match match = fileFilter.Match(filename);
```

And to get the value (number here):

```
if(match.Success)
    string id = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

The matched groups work similar to Perl's matches, `[0]` references the whole match, `[1]` the first sub pattern/match, etc.

Note: In your initial perl code you didn't escape the `.` characters so they'd match any character, not just real periods!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. See the [`Groups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) property of the `Match` class that is returned by a call to [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match.aspx).

In your case, it would be something along the lines of the following:

```
Regex yourRegex = new Regex("^filer_(\d{10}).txt(.gz)?$");
Match match = yourRegex.Match(input);
if(match.Success)
    result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

I don't know, what the `/i` means at the end of your regex, so I removed it in my sample code.

Comment: Should be result = match.Groups[1].Value;

Answer (score 0):

As daniel shows, you can access the content of the matched input via groups. But instead of using default indexed groups you can also use named groups. In the following i show how and also that you can use the static version of Match.

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"^(?i)filer_(?<fileID>\d{10}).txt(?:.gz)?$");
if(m.Success)
    string s = m.Groups["fileID"].Value;
```

The /i in perl means IgnoreCase as also shown by Mario. This can also be set inline in the regex statement using (?i) as shown above.

The last part (?:.gz) creates a non-capturing group, which means that it’s used in the match but no group is created.
I'm not sure if that's what you want, this is how you can do that.